# Switch/Case statement cannot populate cell based on numeric value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using the following case statement with KnockoutJS.

```html
<tbody data-bind="foreach: statusList">
    <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-3" data-bind="text: CompanyName"></td>
        <!-- ko switch: true -->
            <!-- ko case: Status == '1' -->
                <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up col-sm-2"></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko case: $else -->
                <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down col-sm-2"></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <td class="col-sm-7" data-bind="text: Message"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Status can be either 1 or 0, but no matter what I change the comparison to be my cells are either all up arrows or all down arrows. What am I missing here? Is there an easier way to say:

- If Status == 1 display an up arrow
- Else display a down arrow

EDIT:

```html
 <!-- ko if: Status() == '1' -->
    <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up col-sm-2"></td>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: Status() == '1' -->
    <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down col-sm-2"></td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This caused it to work, though I'm not sure why when I would say `text: Status` it would display the 1 or 0.

Comment: Have you tried with `<!-- ko case: Status() == '1' -->`?

Comment: Knockout doesn't have a switch binding out-of-the-box, so it might be helpful to add where you are getting it from. Either way, I'm pretty sure `switch: true` can't be right. Also, were is you VM? And since you only have two states, why not use `if` and `ifnot`?

Comment: I tried if and if not, let me give that another go and I will edit my post.  Switch was from a library on github.

Comment: Most bindings will accept an observable and unwrap it for you; that's why `text: Status` works. But in an expression, you need to unwrap it: `case: Status() == 1`.

Comment: They should think about dropping support for expressions in KO 4. Or introduce a new pattern called Model View (MW)

Comment: I'm just getting into knockout but yes this would make a bit more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: statusList">
    <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-3" data-bind="text: CompanyName"></td>
        <!-- ko switch: true -->
                <td data-bind="case.visible: Status() == '1'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up col-sm-2"></td>
                <td data-bind="case.visible: $else" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down col-sm-2"></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <td class="col-sm-7" data-bind="text: Message"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: This works, has syntax errors in my IDE but none the less it worked just fine. I am glad there are two ways to implement this logic.